# How can add a specified image asset to pubspec and then load the image to AssetImage for the app to present?

Tags: flutter, package, assets

I can't find anywhere teaches how to add a specified image within asset. Actually I don't know which pictures are included in the asset, or if I want to use an image from the Internet or my own photo gallery, I don't know how I can link the picture with the asset and apply it in my code.
Similarly, I also don't know what are included in packages, like font_awesome flutter. How can I check what are included? Thank you!
I think I have solved the above questions with the help of commenters, but I have more questions coming up: Why I was unable to load the asset?
Please see the pictures below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lku6S.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4AS3.png)

Comment: Do you want to add to your project an image and then show it in the app?

Comment: Yes, correct! ...............................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can place your assets in a directory in your project folder.
For example `assets\drawables\` and `assets\icons\`

Then in your `pubspec.yaml` you should declare that folder. In this example:

```dart
# To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/drawables/
    - assets/icons/
```

Than in your code you can use them as follow:

```dart
Image.asset(
            'assets/drawables/image.png',
            width: 200,
          ),
```

For your second question, I think you only have two options:
either look for the library documentation / website, such as [www.fontawesome.com](http://www.fontawesome.com) (the free icons are the one in the library). Or look in the code/package yourself

Comment: Oh yes, I have got the idea. Thank you very much!

Comment: great! do not hesitate to accept an answer if that solve your issue

Comment: Sorry, I have one more question: why can't I load the asset, please see the pictures in my question. I am new here, how can I accept the solution?

Comment: You only have to declare the directory that contains the image. in your case just 'assets' is enough. To accept a solution you have a check next to each answer. You can also upvote them by clicking on the up arrows. That helps other users reputation

Answer (score 0):

Place your picture in a folder named `assets` like this:

[image]

Add this line to your `pubspec.yaml`:

[image]

Then put this somewhere in your code:

```
Image.asset(
        'assets/my_image.png',
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
      );
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have solved the problem, but one more question comes up: Why can't I load the asset? Please see the details in the picture that are included in my question.

Comment: I suggest you to not use space in file names.

Comment: Also you need use it like this: `assets/first_image.png` `assets/second_image.png`. And not in new lines.

Comment: Between assets/first_image.png and assets/second_image.png, I use comma or anything? I tried to just load one image, but still there is an error. The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: assets/OptimizeYourFood1.png

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:224:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:672:14)
<asynchronous suspension>

Comment: Check the "Loading images" part: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images -> You have to put your `AssetImage` in an `Image`